# Is there a way to use the babeltrace2-sink.text.pretty component in the c api

Tags: c, lttng, babeltrace

I'd like to use the babeltrace c api to print out formatted text for a lttng trace.
Is there any way to use the already existing component *babeltrace2-sink.text.pretty*?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance